# ADO.NET - Trouble Getting Output Parameter

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

My DBA created the following Stored Proc which he insists works fine when called in SQL Server:

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[GetParentID]
    @SSHIP_AppID as varchar(50),
    @ParentID as varchar(150) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT @ParentID = a.iBuild_GUID

    FROM dbo.XRef_iBuild_SSHIP as a
    WHERE a.SSHIP_appId = @SSHIP_AppID
    AND a.SSHIP_appId <> ''
END
```

I have created the following ADO.NET Wrapper but I am having trouble getting the output parameter. I keep getting back "OUTPUT" as its value:

```
 private string GetParentId(string appId)
        {
            var connection = new SqlConnection();
            string parentId = String.Empty;
            try
            {
                connection.ConnectionString = "...)
                var command = new SqlCommand("GetParentId", connection);

                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SSHIP_AppID", appId));

                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ParentID", ParameterDirection.Output));

                connection.Open();

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                parentId = (command.Parameters["@ParentId"].Value).ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogError(appId, ex.ToString(), "Interface12 - Cannot get ParentId", null, 0);
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
            return parentId;
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: One error is command.Parameters[@ParentId"] should be ]"@ParentID"] but I still get the same errot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `new SqlParameter("@ParentID", ParameterDirection.Output)` the 2nd argument is treated as the `object value` argument and apparently converted to a string.

(This implicit conversion is, in my opinion, a design flaw in ADO.NET. It should throw an exception for any unknown input type.).

Choose a better overload.